# Unable to make sense of database data in Rails console

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to gather a set of data for current_user so in my controller code I have:

```
@user_workouts = current_user.planned_workouts
```

with planned_workouts being the join table b/w the user and the workouts. When I test that in console:

```
@user_workouts.count
```

I get 4.

When I do:

```
PlannedWorkout.count
```

I get 4.

But when I try using a .each loop for my @user_workouts:

```
@user_workouts.each do |user_workout|
   puts user_workout
end
```

I get far more than 4, I get something like ~25, how is that possible when I tested above how many planned_workouts there are in the table and for the user themselves? I also tried deleting all of the planned_workouts so that the table is empty and created 4 new ones, and still the same outcome. Can it have anything to do with the fact that I'm using add_index in the schema?

EDIT:

My model associations:

```
User.rb
has_many :planned_workouts
has_many :workouts, through: :planned_workouts

Workout.rb
has_many :planned_workouts
has_many :users, through: :planned_workouts

PlannedWorkout.rb
belongs_to :workout
belongs_to :user
```

Comment: I highly doubt it has anything to do with `add_index`. How are you saving your `planned_workout` records?

Comment: Show us your models' associations.  Sounds like something is wrong there.

Comment: @mmichael - I'm saving them via a jquery draggable/sortable, it sends an ajax request once an object is dropped and logs it.

Philip, I'll update my code above w/ the associations

Comment: Could you also post the controller action that receives the AJAX requests to save the records?